# Network up to date on truffle deploy

Tags: blockchain, solidity, contract, truffle

I've been working with `solidity` and `truffle` for a few days to develop a contract. I'm testing using the network created by Ganache an RPC client for build a local blockchain enviroment.

There is one thing I do not understand though.

I follow these steps:

- `truffle deploy`. I deploy my contract on the network.
- `truffle test`. I test my contract.It's OK.
- `truffle deploy`. I try to update my contract. Say me **"Network up to date"**

But if I restart Ganache and update my contract with `truffle deploy`, it works. This is the thing that I don't understand.

Why? Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Are you running `ganache-cli` while you execute the truffle commands?

If you are doing that the contracts are deployed in your private ganache network, and I guess if you try to deploy the same contract again it without changes it wont let you because you will deploy contract that is the same as the one you deployed before.

Comment: Thank you for you explain man! I understand now!

Comment: You can also force a redeploy by running `truffle deploy --reset`

Comment: @alvarofvr I would add that restarting Ganache creates a new empty simulation environment and thus `truffle deploy` starts working again.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Like @Augusto Federico Lemble explain in the comment:

*"If you are doing that the contracts are deployed in your private ganache network, and I guess if you try to deploy the same contract again it without changes it wont let you because you will deploy contract that is the same as the one you deployed before"*

And for correct redeploy like @Adam Kipnis says use:

```
truffle deploy --reset
```

Comment: Thanks that was my issue too. However, I did the following for the current version of Truffle: `truffle migrate --reset --network ropsten`